# Which Java versions support global appmenu

Tags: java, application-development, eclipse, appmenu

yesterday after few updates (some of them in java) the Eclipse lose ability to move it's menu to the global-menu bar.

I was try to remove/add different java from the ubuntu's repositories but it still not showing in the global-menu.

So my question is, what versions of java (including the sun's) supports globalmenu, i don't care what are licenses and other like that. Just I want global's menu back ;)

Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know that is not supported in JAVA. I am also looking for that get fixed. Netbeans also have the same issue and there are bugs filed for it.

Comment: But the interesting in that case, is that it was working before update.

Comment: Does this mean that HUD won't work for Java applications? (Should I open this as a new question?)

Comment: Yes, for these that not using SWT imho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the JVM, it's the GUI toolkit fault. A GUI toolkit is a set of api+libraries that enable apps to be drawn in the screen, think of them as a collection of widgets + a runtime for those.

Eclipse uses the SWT toolkit which looks and feel more natively than other Java toolkits (Swing, etc). The easy explanation for the lost is that the *globalmenu* binding have upgraded and SWT has not (yet) upgraded to support.

Answer (score 0):

With the proyect Java Ayatana (http://code.google.com/p/java-swing-ayatana/), The appmenu for Java 6/7 Swing application is supported.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danjaredg/jayatana
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jayatana
```

Finally, restar your session